# correct date output is not coming

Tags: sql, oracle

my query is :

```
SELECT
  TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'DD-MM-YY') AS "FROM DATE",
  TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TO_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'DD-MM-YY')   AS "TO DATE"
FROM TRN_ACTUAL_TABLE
WHERE TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'DD-MM-YY') BETWEEN '01-08-2018 00:00' AND '20-08-2018 00:00'
AND IS_DELETE=0;
```

output is :

[image: output]

in this output month of october(10th) related dates are coming, but i search for august(8th) dates

Comment: Even if this may not solve your actual problem, instead if converting your date column values to char, I'd rather convert the condition values to date.

Comment: First, why are you storing dates as strings in a DB?  You should store them as some datetime type.  Second you're dong a string comparison instead of a date compaison, so like @Filburt said you should convert the strings you're comparing to dates instead of converting the dates back to a string with a different format.

Comment: But if you are going to do a string comparison of dates then they need to be in a format that has the year then the month and then the day.

Comment: you are writing: to_char between x and y. This won't do what you want. Allways to_char(date,'dd-mon-yyyy') is between '01' and '31'. This are strings. please compare dates, not strings.

Comment: Side note: Why do you need to convert `CHAR->DATE->CHAR` in your `SELECT`? You can simply format the date on the UI of your C# application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd better to use `RR` instead of `YY` and `RRRR` instead of `YYYY` against year 2k problem, and get rid of `TO_CHAR` conversion in the where clause as :

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MM-RRRR HH24:MI:SS'),'DD-MM-RR') AS "FROM DATE",
       TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TO_DATE,'DD-MM-RRRR HH24:MI:SS'),'DD-MM-RR')   AS "TO DATE"
  FROM TRN_ACTUAL_TABLE 
 WHERE TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MM-RRRR HH24:MI:SS') 
    BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-08-2018 00:00:00','DD-MM-RRRR HH24:MI:SS') 
        AND TO_DATE('20-08-2018 00:00:00','DD-MM-RRRR HH24:MI:SS')
        AND IS_DELETE=0;
```

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/NVKBDA2651)

Comment: SELECT
  TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS "FROM DATE",
  TO_DATE(TO_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')  AS "TO DATE"
FROM TRN_ACTUAL_TABLE
WHERE TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') BETWEEN '01-08-2018 00:00' AND '20-08-2018 00:00'
AND IS_DELETE=0; -----still not working, it's showing not valid month....@juharr

Answer (score 0):

You should be comparing dates on both sides of `BETWEEN`, and you should use valid Oracle date literals on the RHS.

```
WHERE
    TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') BETWEEN
        DATE '2018-08-01' AND DATE '2018-08-20' AND ...
```

Comment: How would a format of `DD-MM-YY` work with dates in a `YYYY-MM-DD` format?

Comment: @juharr Sorry answered on a cell phone.  Please consider reversing your downvote.

Comment: This still isn't right as `FROM_DATE` is a string in the `DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS` format.  You'd need to do `TO_DATE(FROM_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')` for this to work.